# Undefined variable error in PHP Application Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sts");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $nama = $_POST['nama'];
          $nomkadpengenalan =$_POST['nomkadpengenalan'];
          $nomtelefon =$_POST['nomtelefon'];
   $nomfaksimili =$_POST['nomfaksimili'];
   $email =$_POST['email'];
   $alamat =$_POST['alamat'];
   $nama2 =$_POST['nama2'];
   $harga =$_POST['harga'];
   $usia =$_POST['usia'];
   $asalusul =$_POST['asalusul'];
   $pemilikasal =$_POST['pemilikasal'];
   $keteranganringkas =$_POST['keteranganringkas'];
   $sejarahkoleksi =$_POST['sejarahkoleksi'];
   $lainlain =$_POST['lainlain'];
   $panjang =$_POST['panjang'];
   $tinggi =$_POST['tinggi'];
   $lebar =$_POST['lebar'];
   $berat =$_POST['berat'];
   $diameter=$_POST['diameter'];
 
   if (!isset($_POST['image']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
   }else{
         $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
         $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
   
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
   
   $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  
   }
     // attempt insert query execution
           $sql = "INSERT INTO tawarankoleksi (nama, nomkadpengenalan, nomtelefon, nomfaksimili, email, alamat, nama2, harga, usia,           asalusul, pemilikasal, keteranganringkas, sejarahkoleksi, lainlain, panjang, tinggi, lebar, berat, diameter,           gambarkoleksi) VALUES ('$nama', '$nomkadpengenalan', '$nomtelefon', '$nomfaksimili', '$email', '$alamat', '$nama2',          '$harga', '$usia', '$asalusul', '$pemilikasal', '$keteranganringkas', '$sejarahkoleksi', '$lainlain', '$panjang',          '$tinggi', '$lebar', '$berat', '$diameter', '$location')";
          if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
          echo "Records added successfully.";
          } else{
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
          }
 
           // close connection
           mysqli_close($link);
 }
?>

<div class="form-style-6">
<form action="" method="post" >
<h1>Bahagian A - Maklumat Peribadi</h1>
<p><b>NAMA : </b></p>
<input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="nama" />
<p><b>NOMBOR KAD PENGENALAN : </b></p>
<input type="text" name="nomkadpengenalan" placeholder="nom kad pengenalan" />
<p><b>NOMBOR TELEFON: </b></p>
<input type="text" name="nomtelefon" placeholder="nom telefon" />
<p><b>NOMBOR FAKSIMILI: </b></p>
<input type="text" name="nomfaksimili" placeholder="nom faksimili" />
<p><b>EMAIL: </b></p>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
<p><b>ALAMAT: </b></p>
<input type="text" name="alamat" placeholder="alamat" />


<h1>Bahagian B - Maklumat Artifak</h1>
<p><b>NAMA :</b></p>
<input type="text" name="nama2" placeholder="nama" />
<p><b>HARGA DITAWARKAN PEMBEKAL :</b></p>
<input type="text" name="harga" placeholder="harga ditawarkan" />
<p><b>USIA :</b></p>
<input type="text" name="usia" placeholder="usia" />
<p><b>ASAL USUL :</b></p>
<input type="text" name="asalusul" placeholder="asal usul" />
<p><b>PEMILIK ASAL :</b></br>
(Sila sertakan nama dan biografi)</p>
<textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="pemilikasal" placeholder="pemilik asal"></textarea>
<p><b>KETERANGAN RINGKAS TENTANG KONDISI DAN FIZIKAL ARTIFAK :</b></br>
(Seperti jenis bahan/motif/kegunaan)</p>
<textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="keteranganringkas" placeholder="keterangan ringkas"></textarea>
<p><b>APAKAH NILAI SEJARAH KOLEKSI :</b></p>
<textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="sejarahkoleksi" placeholder="sejarah koleksi"></textarea>
<p><b>LAIN-LAIN :</b></br>
(maklumat tambahan berkaitan jika perlu sebagai sokongan):</p>
<textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="lainlain" placeholder="lain lain"></textarea>

<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
<p><b>UKURAN: <p><b>
<td>
<p><b>PANJANG :<b>
<input type="text" name="panjang" id="panjang" size="10" /></p>
</td>
<td>
<p><b>TINGGI :</b> 
<input type="text" name="tinggi" id="tinggi" size="10" /></p>
</td>
<td>
<p><b>LEBAR :</b>
 <input type="text" name="lebar" id="lebar" size="10" /></p>
</td>
<td>
<p><b>BERAT :</b> 
<input type="text" name="berat" id="berat" size="10" /></p>
</td>
<td>
<p><b>DIAMETER :</b>
 <input type="text" name="diameter" id="diameter" size="10" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<h1>BAHAGIAN C - SENARAI DOKUMEN</h1>

        <p><b>1. GAMBAR KOLEKSI:</b></br>
        (Sekurang-kurangnya 300dpi format JPEG)
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" height="500" width="500"/>
        
<h1>Bahagian D - Pengesahan / Perakuan </h1>

<p>BERDASARKAN RASA PRIHATIN DAN TANGGUNGJAWAB UNTUK MEMELIHARA WARISAN SEJARAH INI, MAKA SAYA MOHON DIPERTIMBANGKAN BAHAN-BAHAN YANG SAYA INGIN DERMAKAN INI KEPADA JABATAN MUZIUM MALAYSIA. SAYA MENGESAHKAN BAHAWA MAKLUMAT YANG DIKEMUKAN ADALAH BENAR SEPANJANG PENGETAHUAN SAYA SENDIRI. SAYA TELAH MEMBACA DAN MEMAHAMI TERMA DAN SYARAT UNTUK MENDERMA OBJEK/ARTIFAK KEPADA JABATAN MUZIUM MALAYSIA. </p>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

I did this information form in php languge and connect mysql database.Once submit all the data inserted nicely in database expect picture. Picture cannot upload and save data in database. The rest data can insert in mysql database.pls refer pic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `enctype` in your form tag is missing. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: You defined a variable in an if statement, so it's possible that the block did not execute

Comment: Can somebody edit and show me what is the right way.Pls i need this solution immediately.

Comment: @ThillaiKumaran `i need this solution immediately` -> You must have confused SO with a freelancing site. Sorry, it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype in your form tag

```
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  **Your code**
</form>
```

And one more error

```
change  **if (!isset($_POST['image']['tmp_name']))**  to

if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
```

Comment: <input type="file" name="image" id="image" height="500" width="500"/>

how to insert pic in target folder and save link database. Is it my method right? Any better idea?

Comment: Thank you so much dear Shanu k k . You are really awesome. I have one question. After change now the picture can store in folder and the link updated   in database. How to set every picture upload in system have own unique number generated by php and stored in folder. Sometimes people upload different picture but with same name. Any idea?

Comment: You can use random numbers like  $rand=rand();                                                               $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);                                         $fileext=explode('.',$image_name);                                                           $image_new=$rand.'.'.$fileext[1];                                                                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $image_new);                                                                                    try this

Answer (score 0):

in form enctype is missing.add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Can somebody edit and show me what is the right way.Pls i need this solution immediately.

Comment: @ThillaiKumaran    `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sts");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $nomkadpengenalan =$_POST['nomkadpengenalan'];
    $nomtelefon =$_POST['nomtelefon'];
    $nomfaksimili =$_POST['nomfaksimili'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $alamat =$_POST['alamat'];
    $nama2 =$_POST['nama2'];
    $harga =$_POST['harga'];
    $usia =$_POST['usia'];
    $asalusul =$_POST['asalusul'];
    $pemilikasal =$_POST['pemilikasal'];
    $keteranganringkas =$_POST['keteranganringkas'];
    $sejarahkoleksi =$_POST['sejarahkoleksi'];
    $lainlain =$_POST['lainlain'];
    $panjang =$_POST['panjang'];
    $tinggi =$_POST['tinggi'];
    $lebar =$_POST['lebar'];
    $berat =$_POST['berat'];
    $diameter=$_POST['diameter'];
 
    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    }
    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tawarankoleksi (nama, nomkadpengenalan, nomtelefon, nomfaksimili, email, alamat, nama2, harga, usia, asalusul, pemilikasal, keteranganringkas, sejarahkoleksi, lainlain, panjang, tinggi, lebar, berat, diameter, gambarkoleksi) 
            VALUES ('$nama', '$nomkadpengenalan', '$nomtelefon', '$nomfaksimili', '$email', '$alamat', '$nama2', '$harga', '$usia', '$asalusul', '$pemilikasal', '$keteranganringkas', '$sejarahkoleksi', '$lainlain', '$panjang', '$tinggi', '$lebar', '$berat', '$diameter', '$location')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<div class="form-style-6">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <h1>Bahagian A - Maklumat Peribadi</h1>
  <p><b>NAMA : </b></p>
  <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="nama" />
  <p><b>NOMBOR KAD PENGENALAN : </b></p>
  <input type="text" name="nomkadpengenalan" placeholder="nom kad pengenalan" />
  <p><b>NOMBOR TELEFON: </b></p>
  <input type="text" name="nomtelefon" placeholder="nom telefon" />
  <p><b>NOMBOR FAKSIMILI: </b></p>
  <input type="text" name="nomfaksimili" placeholder="nom faksimili" />
  <p><b>EMAIL: </b></p>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
  <p><b>ALAMAT: </b></p>
  <input type="text" name="alamat" placeholder="alamat" />

  <h1>Bahagian B - Maklumat Artifak</h1>
  <p><b>NAMA :</b></p>
  <input type="text" name="nama2" placeholder="nama" />
  <p><b>HARGA DITAWARKAN PEMBEKAL :</b></p>
  <input type="text" name="harga" placeholder="harga ditawarkan" />
  <p><b>USIA :</b></p>
  <input type="text" name="usia" placeholder="usia" />
  <p><b>ASAL USUL :</b></p>
  <input type="text" name="asalusul" placeholder="asal usul" />
  <p><b>PEMILIK ASAL :</b></br>
  (Sila sertakan nama dan biografi)</p>
  <textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="pemilikasal" placeholder="pemilik asal"></textarea>
  <p><b>KETERANGAN RINGKAS TENTANG KONDISI DAN FIZIKAL ARTIFAK :</b></br>
  (Seperti jenis bahan/motif/kegunaan)</p>
  <textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="keteranganringkas" placeholder="keterangan ringkas"></textarea>
  <p><b>APAKAH NILAI SEJARAH KOLEKSI :</b></p>
  <textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="sejarahkoleksi" placeholder="sejarah koleksi"></textarea>
  <p><b>LAIN-LAIN :</b></br>
  (maklumat tambahan berkaitan jika perlu sebagai sokongan):</p>
  <textarea type="text" cols="6" rows="5" name="lainlain" placeholder="lain lain"></textarea>

  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
   <tr>
    <p><b>UKURAN: <p><b>
    <td>
     <p><b>PANJANG :<b>
     <input type="text" name="panjang" id="panjang" size="10" /></p>
    </td>
    <td>
     <p><b>TINGGI :</b> 
     <input type="text" name="tinggi" id="tinggi" size="10" /></p>
    </td>
    <td>
     <p><b>LEBAR :</b>
      <input type="text" name="lebar" id="lebar" size="10" /></p>
    </td>
    <td>
     <p><b>BERAT :</b> 
     <input type="text" name="berat" id="berat" size="10" /></p>
    </td>
    <td>
     <p><b>DIAMETER :</b>
      <input type="text" name="diameter" id="diameter" size="10" /></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <h1>BAHAGIAN C - SENARAI DOKUMEN</h1>
  <p><b>1. GAMBAR KOLEKSI:</b></br>
  (Sekurang-kurangnya 300dpi format JPEG)
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image" height="500" width="500"/>
    
  <h1>Bahagian D - Pengesahan / Perakuan </h1>
  <p>BERDASARKAN RASA PRIHATIN DAN TANGGUNGJAWAB UNTUK MEMELIHARA WARISAN SEJARAH INI, 
  MAKA SAYA MOHON DIPERTIMBANGKAN BAHAN-BAHAN YANG SAYA INGIN DERMAKAN INI KEPADA JABATAN MUZIUM MALAYSIA. 
  SAYA MENGESAHKAN BAHAWA MAKLUMAT YANG DIKEMUKAN ADALAH BENAR SEPANJANG PENGETAHUAN SAYA SENDIRI. 
  SAYA TELAH MEMBACA DAN MEMAHAMI TERMA DAN SYARAT UNTUK MENDERMA OBJEK/ARTIFAK KEPADA JABATAN MUZIUM MALAYSIA. </p>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
 </form>
</div>
```